# Try/Catch blocks in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

for the program that I have been assigned, we have to read from a text file, create an ArrayList of objects called NameInformation that contains the information from the file, and then prompt the user for a name and gender (Gender is one of the variables in the NameInformation class) and the computer will tell how many boys or girls had the given name.

Can files be accessed and used outside of a try catch block? I want to try something like this:

```
try {
   FileReader inFile = new FileReader (FILE_NAME);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println ("The file " + FILE_NAME + " does not exist");
   System.exit(-1);
}

Scanner file = new Scanner (infile);
ArrayList<NameInformation> nameList = new ArrayList<NameInformation>();
```

I tried the above code and kept getting an error message. The only way I could get it to work somewhat was to make the try block massive. Is that the only way to do it? I feel like having a massive try block is incorrect.

I want to add elements to the ArrayList too, but can't seem to get it right.

```
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
   NameInformation babyName = new NameInformation(file.nextLine());
   nameList.add(babyName);
}
```

But this doesn't quite do what I want it to.

Comment: "Quick fix" would be `FileReader inFile = null; try { infile = .... } catch(...) { ... } Scanner file = new Scanner (inFile); ....`. Move the `inFile` variable outside of the `try/catch` block to increase its scope. Also mind the typo in `new Scanner (infile)`, you misspelled your variable.

Comment: If the try block is "massive", it simply means you're having too many lines of code inside a block. Refactor to introduce methods: `try { List<NameInformation> list = readInformationFrom(inFile); }`

Comment: @Tom this quick fix is ugly. It's functional only because the catch block calls System.exit(). If it didn't, the quick fix would cause a  NullPointerException.

Comment: @JBNizet That's  why it is a _quick_ fix and a comment and not a _good_ fix and an answer :P. I personally would use a try-with-resources statement instead.

Comment: @Tom, yes I see that I mistyped inFile in my question. It was supposed to read 'new Scanner (inFile)' like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this and give only error throwing code into try catch block, you are never passing catch block anyway because system exits there, otherwise you should check that file isn't null afterwards:

```
FileReader inFile = null;
try {
   inFile = new FileReader (FILE_NAME);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println ("The file " + FILE_NAME + " does not exist");
   System.exit(-1);
}

Scanner file = new Scanner (infile);
ArrayList<NameInformation> nameList = new ArrayList<NameInformation>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the file should be in Try Catch Block. But you should declare it outside the block to access it outside. Example:

```
FileReader inFile = null;
try {
    inFile = new FileReader (FILE_NAME);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println ("The file " + FILE_NAME + " does not exist");
    System.exit(-1);
}

Scanner file = new Scanner (infile);
ArrayList<NameInformation> nameList = new ArrayList<NameInformation>();
```